# Match Column name stored in another dataframe and replace by its ID

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a master data frame called Master, which contains all the ids of questions.
I have multiple datasets containing those questions as header I want to replace those headers with their id's.

**The Master table looks like this:**

```
Question               ID

gender                 1
sex                    1
what is your gender    1
sexual orientation     1
marital status         2
occupation             3
whats you job          3
```

**df1 looks like this:**

```
gender         marital status  occupation

Male           Single          Doctor
Male           Divorced        Engineer
```

Desired output

```
   1            2                 3                 

   Male        Single            Doctor
   Male        Divorced          Engineer
```

also if any new variable comes in df1 which doesn't have id mentioned in the Master data table, a new ID should be given to it and variable name and id will be updated in **master table**

for eg.

**df2 looks like this:**

```
gender         marital status  country

Male           Single          India
Male           Divorced        UK
```

**desired df2 :**

```
1                 2              4

Male           Single          India
Male           Divorced        UK
```

**updated master table will be:**

```
Question               ID

gender                 1
sex                    1
what is your gender    1
sexual orientation     1
marital status         2
occupation             3
whats you job          3
country                4
```

Comment: How about other questions that share the same ID like sex, what is your gender, and sexual orientation?

Comment: @JayPeerachai  so basically in another dataset if any variable comes with any name for e.g sex or gender or sexual orientation it should be replaced by **id = 1** only because all these variables are referring to the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) by `Series` for set new columns names by another data:

```
df2 = df1.rename(columns=df.set_index('Question')['ID'])
print (df2)
      1         2         3
0  Male    Single    Doctor
1  Male  Divorced  Engineer
```

EDIT:

There are duplicates in `Question` values in `df`, so need create unique `Question` values. One possible solution is remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), here are sample data for see how it working:

```
print (df)
              Question  ID
0               gender  10 <-duplicates, change ID for test
1               gender  15 <-duplicates, change ID for test
2  what is your gender   1
3   sexual orientation   1
4       marital status   2
5           occupation   3
6        whats you job   3
```

You can test what are duplciates in real data:

```
print (df[df.duplicated('Question', keep=False)])
  Question  ID
0   gender  10
1   gender  15
```

---

Removed duplicates and keep first dupe row, here `ID=10`:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates('Question').set_index('Question')['ID'])
Question
gender                 10
what is your gender     1
sexual orientation      1
marital status          2
occupation              3
whats you job           3
Name: ID, dtype: int64

df21 = df1.rename(columns=df.drop_duplicates('Question').set_index('Question')['ID'])
print (df21)
     10        2         3 
0  Male    Single    Doctor
1  Male  Divorced  Engineer
```

Removed duplicates and keep first dupe row, here `ID=15`:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates('Question', keep='last').set_index('Question')['ID'])
Question
gender                 15
what is your gender     1
sexual orientation      1
marital status          2
occupation              3
whats you job           3
Name: ID, dtype: int64

df22 = df1.rename(columns=df.drop_duplicates('Question', keep='last').set_index('Question')['ID'])
print (df22)
     15        2         3 
0  Male    Single    Doctor
1  Male  Divorced  Engineer


print (df.set_index('Question')['ID'].to_dict())
{'gender': 15, 'what is your gender': 1, 'sexual orientation': 1, 'marital status': 2, 'occupation': 3, 'whats you job': 3}



df22 = df1.rename(columns=df.set_index('Question')['ID'].to_dict())
print (df22)
     15        2         3 
0  Male    Single    Doctor
1  Male  Divorced  Engineer
```

EDIT1: If values in master DataFrame not exist and is necessary first append them use:

```
print (df)
              Question  ID
0               gender   1
1                  sex   1
2  what is your gender   1
3   sexual orientation   1
4       marital status   2
5           occupation   3
6        whats you job   3

print (df1) 
  gender marital status country  code1  code2
0   Male         Single   India      4      7
1   Male       Divorced      UK      3      5
```

Get all columns which not exist in `df['Question']`:

```
cols = df1.columns.difference(df['Question'].tolist(), sort=False)
print (cols)
Index(['country', 'code1', 'code2'], dtype='object')
```

Add `ID` next by maximal value:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Question':cols, 
                    'ID': np.arange(df['ID'].max() + 1, len(cols) + df['ID'].max() + 1)})
print (df3) 
  Question  ID
0  country   4
1    code1   5
2    code2   6
```

Append to original `master DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df3], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
              Question  ID
0               gender   1
1                  sex   1
2  what is your gender   1
3   sexual orientation   1
4       marital status   2
5           occupation   3
6        whats you job   3
7              country   4
8                code1   5
9                code2   6
```

Last use original solution:

```
df2 = df1.rename(columns=df.set_index('Question')['ID'])
print (df2)
      1         2      4  5  6
0  Male    Single  India  4  7
1  Male  Divorced     UK  3  5
```

Comment: @jexrael Getting an error: **TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed**

Comment: @HemantSain - Can you test `df2 = df1.rename(columns=df.set_index('Question')['ID'].to_dict())`

Comment: @jezrael I think No need to use `drop_duplicates` with `rename`?

Comment: @HemantSain - Answer was edited for possible solutions.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - If duplicates need remove dupes, so `drop_duplicates` or `to_dict()` is solutions. (to_dict keep last dupe)

Comment: Hmm. But if there are more than two duplicates so always keeping the last one doesn't always make sense, I guess the OP needs to rethink about the duplicate entries in master df or do some preprocessing.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - It depends of data, if there are duplicates with same `ID` then solution is perfect valid, if not, I agree, some preprocessing is necessary ;)

Comment: @jezrael yep, if multiple duplicates with same `ID` then no problem, otherwise require preprocessing +1 :).

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael thanks a lot, to_dict  worked can you please look into updated question It would be great if you can help me out with second part of the question as well

Comment: @HemantSain - Why is for `marital status` value `3` and not `2` in `desired df2 `?

Comment: @HemantSain - I think my solution working for second data too.

Comment: @jezrael in the second data we have a column which is not listed in Master data with its corresponding id we need to create a unique id for that column and update the value in master table as well

Comment: @HemantSain - Not understand, how python know `country` is `4` ? It means because last value in `master table` is `3`, so used `3+1=4` ?

Comment: @jezrael while adding ID next by maximal value getting an error: **TypeError: must be str, not int**

Comment: @HemantSain - So what is `print(df['ID'].dtype)` of original dataset ?

Comment: @jezrael **object** it is

Comment: @HemantSain - So it should be integer? Is possible use `df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)` for convert ID to integers?

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael, I modified the variable type accordingly and now everything is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a rename using the ID of the matching question:

```
df1.columns = [int(master[master.Question==c]['ID'].values) for c in df1.columns]
```

This should work for the multiple possible names for a given column.